# How to create the user if it does not exist?

Tags: java, android, firebase

When the user logon with your google account for the first time in the app, I made this activity to create the user in the database. It's working, but are creating more than one user in the database, and I don't know why.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                goLogInScreen();
            } else {
                final String userGoogleEmail = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                databaseUser.orderByChild("userEmail").equalTo(userGoogleEmail).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            //User already exists
                        } else {
                            //Can create new user
                            String id = databaseUser.push().getKey();
                            User user = new User(id, userGoogleEmail, null);
                            databaseUser.child(id).setValue(user);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Do you mean it runs only when there is no existing user in the DB, but when it does run once, it creates more than one entry for that user in the DB?  If so, how many times does it create a user in the DB?

Comment: Yes man, only when there is no existing in the database, and when run, sometimes that i have tried, varies between 4, 2 and 6 times . @geremy

Comment: Consider using Shared Preferences instead of relying on getCurrentUser() only It may be the issue of sync on firebase! if the user login for the first store a value in SharedPreference. And if the user revisit the app try to retreive the SharedPreference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your are using as an identifier the key generated by the `push()` method and not another identifier and this is actually creating the user again, even if exists in your database.

What i'm recomending you to do, is to change a little bit the logic of saving the data in your database. So in order to solve your problem, i recomand you using in stead of that key, the `email address as an identifier`, because is also unique. Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-database
     |
     --- Users
          |
          --- jon@email,com
          |      |
          |      --- //data
          |
          --- jack@email,com
                 |
                 --- //data
```

As you probably see, i have saved the email addreees in the Firebase database using `,` (comma) and not `.` (dot).

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

This is because Firebase does not allow symbols like `.` in the key name. So to store the values like this, the encoded email is required. To achieve this, i recomand you using the following methods:

```
String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}

String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```

To verify if a user exists, simply put the a listeenr on the `Users` node and use `exists()` method on the dataSnapshot object like this:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = usersDatabaseReference.child(userEmail);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //create user
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Hope this solves your problem.